# Убрать элементы названий контроллеров из Swagger-UI

Tags: java, swagger

Использую swagger 2.9  в проекте

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Я раскидал методы по их назначению, но в итоге в ui добавились новые элементы и остались поля c названиями контроллеров, пустые. Не могу понять как их убрать.
Красным выделены контроллеры, они пустые, их нужно убрать, зелёным выделены вынесенные методы.
[image: Красным выделены контроллеры, они пустые, их нужно убрать, зелёным выделены вынесенные методы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Api(value = "Test API Controller", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, tags = {"test-api-controller"}, description = "Testing API")
```

Єту строку добавьте над именем контроллера.

> Хорошо задан вопрос есть половиной ответа. А вопрос вначале надо
>   задавать дяде гуглу а потом уже сюда

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229661/how-to-remove-controller-list-from-swagger-ui

Comment: К сожалению в английском я слабоват, а на русском инфы не нашёл.
Большое спасибо, помогло. :)

Comment: @ВладимирДубровский зделали то что хотели?

Comment: День добрый. Добавьте подробностей в ответ, а то ответы-ссылки у нас не приветствуются.

Comment: @Jackson750 Да, помогло.
Небольшая поправка. В аннотацию "@Api" у контроллера нужно добавить параметр "tag" совпадающий с "tag" в "@ApiOperation" у любого метода в том же классе.
Тогда они сольются.